# Memory leak when deleting an object that holds a vector of strings

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

I have the following class, `Tuple`:

```
class Tuple {
    public:

    Tuple(){

    }

    Tuple(vector<string> newValueList){
        this->values = newValueList;
    }

    ~Tuple() {

    }
    private:

    vector<string> values;
}
```

When I call the destructor method I get a memory leak (using valgrind):

```
Invalid read of size 8
  at 0x40BE66: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() 
  by 0x40BB2D: Tuple::~Tuple()
```

I am not sure at all why this is happening.  I thought that vectors did their own memory management.

Edit:

Here is an example of how I create a `Tuple`:

```
Tuple* Tuple::duplicate(string value, int count, bool pull){
  Tuple* returnTuple = 0;
  vector<string> newValueList;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < this->values.size(); i++) {
    if (((int)i == count)&&!pull)
      continue;
    else{
      newValueList.push_back(this->values[i]);
    }
  }
  returnTuple = new Tuple(newValueList);
  return returnTuple;
}
```

Comment: How do you create your `Tuple` object?

Comment: This code alone has nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Although you don't need to explicitly set `this`'s values when you're inside a member function already ^^ could just be `values = newValueList`. Though that's obviously not the problem.

Comment: You allocate the `Tuple` with `new` and likely don't `delete` it anywhere. Why are you heap allocating it in the first place?

Comment: "When I call the destructor..." You don't call the destructor (placement-new not withstanding). Either you delete a dynamic allocation and *it* fires it for you, or an automatic instance will fire it upon leaving scope. Which brings us to Yuushi's comment. Where are you deleting that `tuple` you're returning? Valgrind will have an allocation stack trace of where the memory came from, all the way back to `main()`, so why don't you look-at/post *that*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out the solution after your comments.

I had a `vector<Tuple*>` and it was causing memory leaks like crazy.  I went through my whole code and changed each instance of `Tuple*` to just `Tuple` and made the other necessary changes to make sure my code still worked.  After doing that, I had no problems with the destructor for `Tuple`. Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tuple* Tuple::duplicate(string value, int count, bool pull)
```

1. What is use of value?
2. You are allocating objects dynamically

   returnTuple = new Tuple(newValueList);

   Vector is being initialized inside Tuple object. There will be no memory leak if you explicitly delete returnTuple somewhere in your code. You will have to keep track of all objects you create dynamically. Or better suggestion is to go for shared_pointers, which will manage memory release.

Also changing Tuple* to Tuple helped  because you shifted from dynamic/heap allocation to stack allocation. Destructor will be automatically called once you stack objects go out of scope.